# What is the best way to make a page that filters a content type using Ajax

Tags: views

I tried to use Finder module, but I had some issues with pagination and some weird issues when I parameter it to use Ajax, some friends told me that I can use the Views module, but they couldn't tell if it supports or could be hacked to support Ajax calls. (I mean by hacked being extended)

I'm new to drupal, it's been like a two days learning and practicing, and I would appreciate any proposition.

Comment: I would definitely suggest Views. Views has a setting for AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Drupal 7 [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) is easily used and AJAX enabled. Advanced > OTHER > Use AJAX on the view edit screen. There are lots of documents, answers and functions to help you on your way.